# I am trying to add multiple rows to a panelgrid in PrimeFaces

Tags: primefaces

I am trying to have panel grid with multiple columns, and in one column, I need multiple rows.
Using primefaces 3.3  for the same.

What I want is something like this
StoreId  Storename  Categories
 100    testname 
 Cat1   Cat2   Cat3
 $100   $101   $102
 2.5   2.6    2.7
LIke for a StoreId 100, storeName testname, I need 3 rows in categories against that
How will I do it?

Cat1, $100 and 2.5 should be stacked one below the other(3 rows)  in one column 
similarly Cat2, $101 and 2.6 should be stacked as the next column - All under the categies columns against storeid 100 and Storename, test name.- Makes sense?

Comment: No, does not make sense, at least for me. Please rewrite your question and try to explain yourself better..

Comment: You need to review the showcase page of Primefaces and make the example of PanelGrid dynamically

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `p:panelGrid` component inside a `p:column` component to manage multiple rows inside a single cell.